# How to parse a JSON array C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, json, list, parsing

So after doing a web request, I get this JSON string back:

```
{"status":"okay","result":[{"id":8810,"country":"IE","region":"07","city":"Dublin","latitude":53.3331,"longitude":-6.2489,"comment":"407367 donkeys"},{"id":9688,"country":"IE","region":"04","city":"Cork","latitude":51.8986,"longitude":-8.4958,"comment":"454765 donkeys"},{"id":9963,"country":"IE","region":"06","city":"Donegal","latitude":54.65,"longitude":-8.1167,"comment":"315518 donkeys"}]}
```

I'm not sure how to parse it. I have a City class that has id, country, region etc, and I would like to be able to save each one separately in a list so I can add them to a List View for an app.

I have tried this:

```
JObject jobj = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
JToken jstatus = jobj["status"];
JToken jresult = jobj["result"];
status = (String)jstatus;
JArray arrayOfCities = JArray.Parse(jsonString);

        if (status.Equals("okay"))
        {
            foreach (JObject o in arrayOfCities.Children<JObject>())
            {
                foreach (JProperty p in o.Properties())
                {
                    id = p.Name + p.Value.ToString();// (String)jresult["id"];

                    country = (String)jresult["country"];
                    region = (String)jresult["region"];
                    city = (String)jresult["city"];
                    latitude = (String)jresult["latitude"];
                    longitude = (String)jresult["longitude"];
                    comment = (String)jresult["comment"];
                }
            }
        }
```

However I keep getting parse errors in it. I tried a few things, but none end up working.
How could I parse each part of the array separately and save it to a City List.
Thanks

Comment: JArray arrayOfCities = JArray.Parse(jsonString); should probably read "JArray arrayOfCities = JArray.Parse(jresult);"

Comment: @It wont work because jsonString is a string filled with the web request i have at the top of my post. jresult is a JToken

Answer (score 9):

You should use [`DeserializeObject`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm). Here's an example:

```
public class CitiesResponse
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public List<City> Result { get; set; }
}
var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CitiesResponse>(jsonString);
// response.Result is your list of cities
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, what do  do when I do List<Cities> t = response.Result?

I can't view whats inside the object when I set breakpoints so I don't know if it's working?

Comment: You can put a breakpoint on any line after `var response = ...` and inspect the resulting objects in your debugger, or put lines outputting data about it.

Comment: Hm, your `City` class should be roughly like this in order to work: http://pastebin.com/djDKYaJs (generated with http://json2csharp.com/) Json.net is pretty flexible, however, especially when you configure it with attributes. If you can't figure it out, you can ask a new question about this. If you do that, include your `City` and `CitiesResponse` classes and example JSON data.