# How do you get the selling_price? (Xamarin Forms)

Tags: c#, json

This is my code:

```
dynamic resultObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Result);
string final = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resultObject);
```

This my the result of final (JSON):

[image]

How do get the selling_price field? like doing final.selling_price?

My class:

```
public class ItemPriceJson {
        public string item_price_id { get; set; }
        public string item_code { get; set; }
        public string item_desc { get; set; }
        public string trnx_unit { get; set; }
        public string price_level_id { get; set; }
        public string price_level_code { get; set; }
        public string selling_price { get; set; }
    } // itemPriceJson
```

Comment: you can create a model class with respect to the json response. It creates the POCO for you

Comment: Paste the text and not screenshots from text

Comment: it still doesn't work here even with a class.

Comment: What is the reason to deserialize a json just to serialize it again?

Comment: Did you notice that your json is an **array**? If you deserialize it, then you have to deserialize it to a collection like List<ItemPriceJson>

Comment: It's the same question type almost everytime when I see `json` tag.. [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41849358/deserialize-array-in-json-into-class-object/41849456#41849456) there are some "details" on how to distinguish if your `json` is an array of objects or object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse a JSON array C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19941878/how-to-parse-a-json-array-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not deserializing the json to a dynamic object properly. First of all, it's an array, not an object.

So, try it like this:

```
dynamic resultObject = JArray.Parse(Result); //Dynamic object.
var sellingPrice = resultObject[0].selling_price; //Get the selling price. Could also use some casting here.
```

Comment: Why not `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ItemPriceJson>>( Result )` ?

Comment: OP didn't specify his class code when I wrote this.

Answer (score 0):

Create a POCO class which describes the object for example;

```
public class MyItemObject
{
    public string item_price_id { get; set; }
    public string item_desc { get; set; }
    public string trnx_unit { get; set; }
}
```

Then use JsonConvert to deserialize a instance of the object.

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyItemObject>(json);
```

**EDIT**

As json is a list/collection deserialize as a list type;

```
var listResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyItemObject>>(json);
```

Comment: Nope, the json contains an array / collection

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ItemPriceJson {
    public string item_price_id { get; set; }
    public string item_code { get; set; }
    public string item_desc { get; set; }
    public string trnx_unit { get; set; }
    public string price_level_id { get; set; }
    public string price_level_code { get; set; }
    public string selling_price { get; set; }
}
```

And you can use the Newtonsoft json library

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ItemPriceJson>>(jsonstring);
```

Comment: No. It is an array.

Comment: ok then we can use JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ItemPriceJson>>(jsonstring);

Comment: You cannot call `result.selling_price` because `List<>` doesn't have property/field named `selling_price`.

Comment: oh,, its a mistake, earlier I convert json object to POCO, then it is JSON array, that's why.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your class to

```
public class ItemPriceJson {
    public int item_price_id { get; set; }
    public string item_code { get; set; }
    public string item_desc { get; set; }
    public string trnx_unit { get; set; }
    public int price_level_id { get; set; }
    public string price_level_code { get; set; }
    public int selling_price { get; set; }
} // itemPriceJson
```

and deserialize it with

```
var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ItemPriceJson>>( Result );
```

because the json result contains an array of objects and so you need a collection for deserialization